# Почему разделывают под орех?

Tags: фразеология

"Разделать под орех" говорят о том, что кого-то победили на голову, разнесли в пух и прах и т.д.
А почему, собственно, под орех?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Выражение «разделать под орех» разными фразеологическими словарями толкуется несколько по-разному. Наиболее полное толкование – в «Фразеологическом словаре русского литературного языка» А. И. Федорова (М., АСТ Астрель, 2001):
>
> 1. кого. Зло и беспощадно ругать, распекать, критиковать за что-либо. – А ты, управляющий, слепой верблюд. Должно быть, и на плоту не бываешь? Вон та рябая под орех нас разделывает (Ф. Гладков. «Вольница»).
> 2. кого. Полностью побеждать в игре, в драке, в сражении. – Отбой тревоге, – весело приказал он, расстегивая канадку. – Их счастье, а то бы мы их под орех разделали (В. Пикуль. «Океанский патруль»).
> 3. что. Делать мастерски, хорошо, безупречно. – А мы без тебя тут, пока ты с обозом тащился, все дела под орех разделали. Продали шерсть Черепахину и так, как дай Бог всякому (Чехов. «Степь»).
>
> Пришло оно в литературный язык из речи столяров и первоначально обозначало «придать поверхности столярного изделия рисунок древесины орехового дерева», для чего требовалась соответствующая обработка, причем довольно трудоемкая.                   Вопрос  в  том,  как  столярный  термин  приобрёл  современное  значение.  Должно  быть  промежуточное  значение.  Думается,  развитие  выражения  шло  таким  образом.  Отделать  или  разделать  под  орех - это  сделать  чистую,  умелую  работу,  но  в  то  же  время  сделать  подделку,  имитацию  дорогого  материала.  Можно  было  сделать  фанеровку,  а  можно  было  и  раскрасить  красками,  нарисовать  текстуру.  Грубее,  но  дешевле.  Другими  словами,  сделать  так,  что  и  не  узнаешь  родимую  сосну  или  берёзу.  Перейдём  от  профессиональной  материи  к  грубой  прозе  жизни.  Разделать  под  орех - это  избить так,  что  мордочку  под  синяками  и  не  сразу  узнаешь.  Это  значение  сначала,  возможно,  бытовало  только  в  столярной  среде,  но  потом  распространилось  и  получило  более  широкое  значение:  разбить  кого-либо  в  пух  и  прах,  а  когда  появилась  возможность  сделать  это  словами,  то  беспощадно  раскритиковать  на  собрании  или  в  печати.  С  этим  значением  фразеологизма  мы  сейчас  и  имеем  дело.